# Why my pycharm can not debug forever?

Tags: debugging, pycharm, pydev

My computer version is Win7.
And what ever .py I debug, this pycharm will show me en error like this:

[image]

ValueError: bad marshal data (string ref out of range)

So what's wrong with pycharm, I tried to user newest version of pycharm but I helpless, the same error will show again.
I used to reinstall my win7 (becauser I have Shadow Mode software) and it work for a period.

Is there body have a good solution?

Comment: if you want to check your pycharm debug feature, you'd better to start with  a simple (e.g. helloworld) script.

Comment: not pycharm debug business, the reason I found out just because of installing two version of python on win7.It's the same like you can not use pip for python3 as you install the 2.X and 3.X on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is directly related to the pydev debugger in this case... my bet is that for some reason you're having corrupted .pyc files (don't know why thought).

Try cleaning your .pyc files from your pycharm installation and your own files and run it again (you may try running with pydev which has the same debugger backend if you want to see if you reproduce the issue there).

Comment: Thx for your answering my question, I have already found out how it comes out as I have installed two version of python. If I  debug my .py using 3.x version there is nothing error. But I can not fix that problem even I reinstall my pycharm or uninstall my Anaconda3. The bug was driving me mad whole yesterday. Could you please give me some advice as a poor guy is seeking help.